# OutOfMemory exception in dataGridView

Tags: c#-4.0, datagridview

I am using 2 datagridview to see the data in a windows form application.

The first DGV show the products according to the ids passed to them.

On click of VIEW as of my one column in DGV1, it passes the product id to and fetch the complete records from database and show the records to the other DGV2.

this is my code:

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value == (Object)"View")
                {
                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                    }

                    int prod_id = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
                    dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
                    dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();

                    retFindProducts = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT tf_history.thefind_id, tf_product.product_id, tf_product.`name`, tf_product.product_url, tf_product.image_tpm, tf_product.image_thefind, tf_product.image_accuracy, (SELECT MIN(tf_h.price) FROM tf_history AS tf_h WHERE tf_h.thefind_id = tf_history.thefind_id) as price, oc_product.price AS priceTPM FROM tf_product LEFT JOIN tf_history ON tf_product.product_id = tf_history.product_id AND tf_product.thefind_id = tf_history.thefind_id LEFT JOIN oc_product ON tf_product.product_id = oc_product.product_id WHERE  tf_product.product_id = @product_id", con);
                    historyData = new MySqlCommand("SELECT price, date from tf_history WHERE thefind_id = @thefind_id", con);

                    retFindProducts.CommandTimeout = 300;
                    historyData.CommandTimeout = 300;

                    retFindProducts.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_id", prod_id);
                    dr = retFindProducts.ExecuteReader();
                    retFindProducts.Parameters.Clear();

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
                        long fI = Convert.ToInt64(dr["thefind_id"]);
                        //if (!findId.Exists(p => p.Item1 == fI))
                        findId.Add(new Tuple<long>(fI));
                        decimal findPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["price"]);
                        decimal tpmPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["priceTPM"]);

                        if (findPrice > tpmPrice)
                        {
                            dataGridView2.Rows[cnt].Cells[4].Style.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                            dataGridView2.Rows[cnt].Cells[4].Style.Font = new Font(dataGridView2.DefaultCellStyle.Font.FontFamily, 9, FontStyle.Regular);
                        }
                        else if (findPrice < tpmPrice)
                        {
                            dataGridView2.Rows[cnt].Cells[4].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            dataGridView2.Rows[cnt].Cells[4].Style.Font = new Font(dataGridView2.DefaultCellStyle.Font.FontFamily, 10, FontStyle.Bold);
                        }

                        dataGridView2.Rows[cnt].Cells[0].Value = Image.FromFile(dr["image_tpm"].ToString());
                        dataGridView2.Rows[cnt].Cells[1].Value = Image.FromFile(dr["image_thefind"].ToString());
                        dataGridView2.Rows[cnt].Cells[2].Value = dr["name"].ToString();
                        dataGridView2.Rows[cnt].Cells[3].Value = dr["product_url"].ToString();
                        dataGridView2.Rows[cnt].Cells[4].Value = dr["price"].ToString();
                        dataGridView2.Rows[cnt].Cells[5].Value = dr["image_accuracy"].ToString();

                        cnt++;
                    }

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
                    {
                        row.Height = 60;
                    }
                    dr.Close();
                }
```

Now, the outofexception does not comes on first time of the click, but it comes after 5-8 clicks on the VIEW column of DGV1.
How can i clear up the memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to dispose and create datagridview manually. The Code can be like this:

```
            dgv.Dispose();
            dgv = new DataGridView();
            DataGridViewColumn col1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            DataGridViewColumn col2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            DataGridViewColumn col3 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            DataGridViewColumn col4 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            DataGridViewColumn col5 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

            col1.HeaderText = "COl1";
            col2.HeaderText = "COl2";
            col3.HeaderText = "COl3";
            col4.HeaderText = "COl4";
            col5.HeaderText = "COl5";
            dgv = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            dgv.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            dgv.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(59, 101);
            dgv.Name = "dataGridView1";
            dgv.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 150);
            dgv.TabIndex = 2;

            dgv.Columns.Add(col1);
            dgv.Columns.Add(col2);
            dgv.Columns.Add(col3);
            dgv.Columns.Add(col4);
            dgv.Columns.Add(col5);

        this.Controls.Add(dgv);

        dgv.ColumnCount = 5;

        dgv.Visible = true;
```